# ThreeJS - Apply multiple textures depending on the object's position

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, mesh

I recently started using ThreeJS and decided to create a model of the Earth using a Sphere mesh.  I also created a model of the Sun and would like to apply two different textures to the Earth model, based on its position.  More specifically, I'd like to apply a "night" texture on the side of the Earth sphere not facing the Sun and a "day" texture on the side that faces the Sun.  The "night" version displays the Earth as generally darker and it features lights shining.

On top of this, I feel that some sort of "feathering" would make it a bit more lifelike, so that there's a soft transition between the two textures, rather than a hard delineation.  How could I go about this?

[image: Here is a screenshot of what I'm trying to create]

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know there are two methods to achieve what you want.
The simplest is to use "THREE.MeshPhongMaterial", and apply the textures as below.

```
const plight = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1);
plight.position.set(0, 0, 0)
scene.add(plight);

const geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(radius, 32, 32);

const night_texture_loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
const night_texture = night_texture_loader.load('earth_nightmap.jpg');

const day_texture_loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
const day_texture = day_texture_loader.load('earth_daymap.jpg');

const earth_specularmap_loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
const earth_specularmap = earth_specularmap_loader.load('earth_specularmap.tif');

const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    map: day_texture,
    emissiveMap: night_texture,
    emissive: new THREE.Color(0x888888),
    emissiveIntensity: 1,
    specularMap: earth_specularmap,
    specular: 1,
    shininess: 30,
});

const earth = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
earth.position.set(1, 0, 0)
scene.add(earth);
```

The second method is to use a custom Shader, "THREE.ShaderMaterial", but this is much more complicated to set up (I didn't succeed).